# Can I automatically convert user flows to custom policy xml?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

When I create a new user flow, I have download button that allows me to download an XML definition of the flow as sown below:

[image]

Can I assume that the downloaded XML file is actually a custom policy definition that is equivalent with the actual user flow?

I am asking since if that answer is yes, I can use XML version of the user flows as a starting generated code for the user profile - so it saves me time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - the downloaded XML file is actually a custom policy definition.

But it doesn't conform to the starter pack in some ways.

But yes, you can use it as a guide.

Comment: Not sure why this is the accepted answer. You can't upload the downloaded User Flow file and immediately upload it and run as a Custom Policy, it throws errors because of what it extends from. You have to change a lot of things in that file to get it to run, and only THEN can you use it as a starting point.